# How to Capture Wordpress $_POST

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm working on a website that has a shortcode subscription form on a page and I'd like access to the $_POST data. Is it possible for me to add my own shortcode to that page to access the $_POST data?

Thanks
Mike

```
function mgc_init(){
        var_dump($_POST);
}

add_shortcode('mgc','mgc_init');
```

**UPDATE**: I'm not sure if I'm placing this shortcode in the right place in order to get access to the $_POST data. The form that gets submitted is inside a different shortcode (on the same Wordpress page). Do I need a hook get the $_POST data?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that snippet.

Comment: I'm still not capturing the $_POST data when I add this shortcode to my Wordpress page. Should I consider using a add_action()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps ;]

```
// put this in your functions.php or plugin functions
function wpd_post_parse() {

    var_dump($_POST);
    // or other actions on $_POST

}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_post_parse' );
```